# How to authenticate PHP random generated pin and serial to login

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP.

I am developing a site that will enable parents check school terminal results of their kids online. I have been able to create a script that does the query and displays the result. All is working fine. But my BIG problem is that I want them to buy the result PIN and Serial Numbers from the School . This is one set of PIN and Serial to only one admission No.
The work flow is that, when students enter their Admission No, it checks the students table, if the Admission No. exists, then the pin and serial are entered, if there exists correct pin and serial from the card table, it updates the card table row called stureg with the Admission No.. then it headers them to the dashboard where the result is visible.
The BIG problem now is that, the randomly generated numbers (PIN and SERIAL) does not authenticate from the second row with id of 2.

These are the scripts:

PIN GENERATOR PAGE

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['ActionAxeIsGood']) && $_POST['ActionAxeIsGood'] == "txtLoginCNumberMaxText") { // checks form values

    include "php/Dbfile.php";

    $student_reg = $_POST['txtMatricNumber'];
    $CardPin     = $_POST['txtCardPin'];
    $CardSerial  = $_POST['txtCardSerial'];
    //$student_password = $_POST['password'];
    $ip =   preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    $r  =   preg_replace('#[^A-Z0-9\'/\'\'-\']#', '', $student_reg);
    $p  =   preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $CardPin);
    $s  =   preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $CardSerial);

    $errors = array();
    $msg    = '';

    if ($r == "") {
        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Matric No.</p>';
    }
    if ($p == "") {
        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Pin</p>';
    }
    if ($s == "") {
        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Serial</p>';
    }

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        // if there are errors, print them out as a list
        $msg = '<p>Please correct the following errors:</p>';
        $msg .= '<ul>';

        foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
            $msg .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
        $msg .= '</ul>';

    } else { // if no errors then go on

        $sql_student   = "SELECT id, firstname, reg FROM students WHERE reg='$r' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1 ";
        $student_query = mysqli_query($DBconn, $sql_student);
        $student_row   = mysqli_fetch_row($student_query);

        $log_id   = $student_row[0];
        $log_name = $student_row[1];
        $log_reg  = $student_row[2];

        //check if Card Serial n Pin Exists
        $sqlc         = "SELECT id FROM card ";
        $CardSerial_c = mysqli_query($DBconn, $sqlc);
        $Cardrowc     = mysqli_fetch_row($CardSerial_c);
        $DB_Id        = $Cardrowc[0];


        $sql          = "SELECT pin, serialme FROM card WHERE id='" . $DB_Id . "' LIMIT 1";
        $CardSerial_q = mysqli_query($DBconn, $sql);
        $Cardrow      = mysqli_fetch_row($CardSerial_q);
        $DB_Pin       = $Cardrow[0];
        $DB_Serial    = $Cardrow[1];

        if ($r == $log_reg) {

            if ($p == $DB_Pin && $s == $DB_Serial) {

                header("location: student/dashboard.php?q=$log_name");

            } else {
                echo "string";
            }

        } else {
            echo "No";
        }

    }
}

?>

<form id="login_form" method="post">
  <div id="FillHolder">
    <div id="txt-container">
      <div id="signIn">
        <strong>Check Result</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="formholder">
        <input id="txtMatricNumber" class="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Registration Number/Matric No" name="txtMatricNumber" >
      </div>
      <div class="formholder">
        <input id="txtMatricNumber" class="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Card Pin" name="txtCardPin" >
      </div>
      <div class="formholder">
        <input id="txtMatricNumber" class="textinput" type="password" placeholder="Card Serial" name="txtCardSerial" >
      </div>
      <div class="formholder">
        <input name="ActionAxeIsGood" type="hidden" id="bLogin"  value="txtLoginCNumberMaxText" />
        <button id="bLogin" class="submitbtn" type="submit">Check Result</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain better and clean code?

Comment: @MirkoBrombin, i don't know what else you want than this

Comment: Explains well what you want

Comment: I want to use a login field that contains username, pin and serial.

Comment: let me check your source

Comment: Then store generated the pin and serial by a click of button which is two php  rand() numbers. The next is that when user enters their username, pin and serial which will be provided by the admin. It logs the user and header to a dashboard

Comment: There are an error on line 99: expecting 2  '}'

Comment: I have added that but the problem is that it does not recognize the pin and serial to exist in the database

Comment: Let me check your code

Comment: first error: if (!empty($errors)) {} it doesn't start, make a single query to do all your steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making the id of the card table to auto_increment from 1333242663 then i used it as the Card Pin while the php rand() generated code serves as the Card Serial. It works fine now.

```
<?php

            if (isset($_POST['ActionAxeIsGood']) && $_POST['ActionAxeIsGood'] == "txtLoginCNumberMaxText") {// checks form values

            include "php/Dbfile.php";

                $student_reg = $_POST['txtMatricNumber'];
                $CardPin = $_POST['txtCardPin'];
                $CardSerial = $_POST['txtCardSerial'];
                //$student_password = $_POST['password'];
                $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '',getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));


                $r = preg_replace('#[^A-Z0-9\'/\'\'-\']#', '',$student_reg);
                $p = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '',$CardPin);
                $s = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '',$CardSerial);





                    $errors = array();
                    $msg = '';


                    if ($r == "") {
                        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Matric No.</p>';

                    }if ($p == "") {
                        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Pin</p>';

                    }if ($s == "") {
                        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Serial</p>';

                    }



                    if(!empty($errors)) {
                    // if there are errors, print them out as a list
                    $msg = '<p>Please correct the following errors:</p>';

                    $msg .= '<ul>';

                    foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                        $msg .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
                    }
                    $msg .= '</ul>';


                    }else {// if no errors then go on


                    $sql_student = "SELECT id, firstname, reg FROM students WHERE reg='$r' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1 ";
                    $student_query = mysqli_query($DBconn, $sql_student);
                    $student_row = mysqli_fetch_row($student_query);

                    $log_id = $student_row[0];  
                    $log_name = $student_row[1];
                    $log_reg = $student_row[2];




                    $sql = "SELECT serialme FROM card WHERE id='".$p."' LIMIT 1";
                    $CardSerial_q = mysqli_query($DBconn, $sql);
                    $Cardrow = mysqli_fetch_row($CardSerial_q);
                    $DB_Serial = $Cardrow[0];

                    if ($r == $log_reg) {

                        if ($s == $DB_Serial) {

                    $_SESSION['student_id'] = $log_id;  
                    $_SESSION['student_name'] = $log_name;
                    $_SESSION['student_reg'] = $log_reg;

                            header("location: student/dashboard.php?q=$log_name");

                        }else {
                            echo "Invalid Serail";
                        }




                    }

                }// if no errors then go on ends




                }//if isset
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

if i ve really understood your situation... the problem is this part of code:

```
$sqlc = "SELECT id FROM card ";
$CardSerial_c = mysqli_query($DBconn, $sqlc);
$Cardrowc = mysqli_fetch_row($CardSerial_c);
$DB_Id = $Cardrowc[0];


$sql = "SELECT pin, serialme FROM card WHERE id='".$DB_Id."' LIMIT 1";
$CardSerial_q = mysqli_query($DBconn, $sql);
$Cardrow = mysqli_fetch_row($CardSerial_q);
$DB_Pin = $Cardrow[0];
$DB_Serial = $Cardrow[1];
```

I think u can do everything with one query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM students s JOIN card c on s.reg = c.stureg WHERE c.stureg = '$r' AND pin = '$p' AND serialme = '$s'" 
$result = mysqli_query($DBconn,$query);
if($result->num_rows>0){
  header("location: student/dashboard.php?q=$log_name");
}else{
  echo "BAD LOGIN";
}
```

Comment: echo $r $p $s before this script.. what you get??

Comment: Can you give me idea on how i can make card pin and serial that are numbers?

Comment: $r = 15/SRC001 , $p = 1394043551 and $s = 454273

Comment: It works in the first card pin and serial pin but does not works on others like from id of 2 in the card table –

Comment: So probably you ve bad data in you database

Answer (score 0):

Remember to clear your source.

Your code have some problems and your query are redundant.

This:

```
if (!empty($errors)) {}
```

cannot do anything.

Try this, I cannot test it because I haven't your sql:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['ActionAxeIsGood']) && $_POST['ActionAxeIsGood'] == "txtLoginCNumberMaxText") { // checks form values

    include "php/Dbfile.php";

    $student_reg = $_POST['txtMatricNumber'];
    $CardPin     = $_POST['txtCardPin'];
    $CardSerial  = $_POST['txtCardSerial'];
    //$student_password = $_POST['password'];
    $ip =   preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    $r  =   preg_replace('#[^A-Z0-9\'/\'\'-\']#', '', $student_reg);
    $p  =   preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $CardPin);
    $s  =   preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $CardSerial);

    if ($r == "") {
        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Matric No.</p>';
    }
    if ($p == "") {
        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Pin</p>';
    }
    if ($s == "") {
        $msg = '<p style="color: maroon;">Enter Serial</p>';
    }

    if (isset($msg)) {
      if($msg == "") {
        // if there are errors, print them out as a list
        $msg = '<p>Please correct the following errors:</p>';
        $msg .= '<ul>';

        foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
            $msg .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
        $msg .= '</ul>';
      }
    } else { // if no errors then go on

      $query = "SELECT * FROM students s JOIN card c on s.reg = c.stureg WHERE c.stureg = '$r' AND pin = '$p' AND serialme = '$s'" 
      $result = mysqli_query($DBconn,$query);
      if($result->num_rows>0){
        header("Location: student/dashboard.php?q=$log_name");
      }
      else{
        echo "BAD LOGIN";
      }
    }
}

?>
```

Query by @Vanojx1

Comment: //sql for card

            -- Table structure for table `card`
            --

            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `card` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `stureg` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
              `serialme` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `pin` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `semester` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

Comment: It works in the first card pin and serial pin but does not works on others like from id of 2 in the card table